# Shopify Cart Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I'm trying to do this in my Shopify theme for Ajaxed cart and add to cart. Add to cart works perfectly, but if I want to change a div if an item has been added, it won't happen:

```
 Shopify.onItemAdded = function(line_item) {
    $('cart').update('Added '+line_item.title + '...');
    Shopify.getCart();
  }
```

But nothing changes. This works however:

```
 Shopify.onItemAdded = function(line_item) {
    alert('yass');
  };
```

Why doesn't the div update when an item is added to cart?

Comment: Are you sure `update()` is a valid method from the object you are calling it on?

Comment: No, what do you recommend that I use? @Anthony

Comment: that really depends on the actual methods/DOM, etc. If you are just trying to change the contents of a div with an id of `cart` to have that message, I would think `$('#cart').html('Added '+line_item.title + '...');` would work, assuming the `$` object is a `JQuery` base object. The shopify documentation sucks so I can't tell what `getCart()` is supposed to do. Probably what you have is fine.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, works perfectly. Do you know how I can just update the div when an item is added?

Comment: Do you mean how to add to instead of replace the content? You probably should read jquery documentation, starting at :http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: No, I mean simply to refresh the div so the content that is inside the div changes as you add a new item @Anthony